# Severe & Bizzare performance issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, optimization, visual-c++

**Update**
Ok, I removed the 3 `cout`s and replaced it with `*buffer = 'a'`, and there was a big performance difference. Removing that line made the program 2x as fast. If you go on godbolt and compile it using `msvc`, that single line of code changes most of the program. (It adds a whole lot more complexity)

**The following might seem extremely weird, but it's true on my computer:**

Alright, so I was doing some benchmarking of some code, and I noticed extremely weird performance anomalies that were 100% consistent. I'm running `windows-10` and `visual-studio-2019`. Basically, deleting a line of code that is **never** called completely changes the performance of the program.

**Here is exactly what to do:**

1. Create new VS-2019 Console C++ App project
2. Set the configuration to **Release & x64**
3. Paste the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
class Test {
public:
    size_t length;
    size_t doublingVal;
    char* buffer;
    Test() : length(0), doublingVal(2) {
        buffer = static_cast<char*>(malloc(1));
    }
    ~Test() {
        std::cout << "called" << "\n";
        std::cout << "called" << "\n";
        std::cout << "called" << "\n"; // Remove this line and the time decreases DRASTICALLY (ie remove line 14)
    }
    void append() {
        if (doublingVal == length) {
            doublingVal <<= 1;
        }
        *buffer = 'a';
        ++length;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test test;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < static_cast<size_t>(1024) * 1024 * 1024 * 4; ++i) {
        test.append();
    }
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << "\n";
}
```

Run the program using CTRL+F5, not in debug. Now remember how long it takes to run. (a few seconds)

**Then, in the destructor of `Test`, remove the third line which has the comment.**

Run the program again, and you should see that the performance increases **drastically**. I tested this **exact** same code with 4 different projects all brand new, and 3 different computers.

The destructor is called at the very end, when the entire program is finished measuring time. The extra `cout` shouldn't affect anything.

**Edit:**
You can also see a similar thing go on if you remove the 3 `cout`'s and replace it with a single `*buffer = 'a'`. Then CTRL+F5 once again, record the time, and then remove that line we just added. Then run it again and the time magically decreases by half.

WTF is going on, and how do you solve the weird performance difference?

Comment: Does your visual Studio edition come with a profiler? If it does, that's the tool to use.

Comment: You removed code, time decreased. What is wrong with that? **and how do I solve it** - solve what?

Comment: I recommend using `std::chrono::steady_clock` rather than `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock.`. As `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` can be an alias of the system clock.

Comment: I removed a line of code that was not called until the end of the benchmarking. Why would that effect the benchmarked time?

Comment: @WalrusEater100 Output buffering?

Comment: @Galik Yup, i tried steady_clock with no differences

Comment: @user14063792468 What do you mean? std::cout is never called until the program completely exists

Comment: Has anybody tested this? I'm wondering if any of you can reproduce it. I listed 3 exact steps to do so. Make sure to copy and paste the code exactly

Comment: Hint: flush an output after all prints in destructor.

Comment: @WalrusEater100 I wasn't expecting it to fix your problem, it's just a general recommendation when timing things. The `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` has no guarantees in the standard as to quality and can vary considerably as the system tries to stay synchronized to internet time (for example). `std::chrono::steady_clock` is better for timing things.

Comment: Turn on the optimizer and most of the program should just vanish. It doesn't do anything. A smart compiler should realize that at the end of the loop `*buffer` is `'a'` and length is 4 billion, but since they are never used, they can be discarded as well.

Comment: @user4581301 What do you mean? I turned on Release with optimizations and it prints out the time it takes to go through the loop

Comment: Your program has two observable outputs: The three "called"s and the elapsed time. Everything else that happens can be optimized out because it doesn't change the observable behaviiour.

Comment: @user4581301 How come the time changes so much though? And if it optimized everything out, doesn't that mean the for loop would be gone as well taking the time down to 0ms?

Comment: @user4581301 _Everything else that happens can be optimized out because it doesn't change the observable behaviour._  It isn't though, I tested it (compiling from the command line with /Ox).  That said, I couldn't reproduce the OP's findings, either.

Comment: Yup, but for some reason the compiler can't see that the program does nothing.

Comment: @user4581301 Code is too complex for the compiler to figure it out, seems.  The fact that a member variable is being incremented in the loop may be a factor.

Comment: @PaulSanders Hmm thats weird. I'm using the latest version of VS-2019 and all I did was create a new project, and set it to Release and x64. Everything else stood the same

Comment: @PaulSanders Also, if you introduce any extra lines it breaks it. Before this, I had a vector initialized that had **no references**. Simply removing the declaration increased the time by a whole second.

Comment: @user14063792468 It's not completely because of the output buffering. If you remove all the couts in the destructor, and replace it with `*buffer = 'a'`, then run the program and record the time, then remove that line, the time decreases

Comment: Under some circumstances the compiler can see that most of the code  does nothing whatsoever, and simply optimizes it away. But, adding another line of code, here or there, apparently generates enough complexity that the compiler can't see the forest for the trees, and ends up generating a bunch of code that loops around, doing nothing. Why? Who knows. C++ compilers are mysterious beasts.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik However why does changing the number of `cout`'s affect its complexity? What is the difference between 1 `cout` in the destructor and 2? Or 2 and 3? However changing the number of `cout`'s from 2 to 3 doubles the time taken

Comment: That's where I'm headed. Reasoning about this code is kind of pointless. Maybe without that extra `cout` the compiler can detect and discard more useless code.

Comment: Still worth hitting it with the profiler to see what soaks up that extra time.

Comment: However the reason why I dug down this hole in the first place was because I had some actual code which did stuff, and noticed its performance was 4x worst then just not putting it in the class. After removing junk, I figured that adding a line of useless code broke everything

Comment: @user4581301 I did hit it up with the profiler, and it was just `append` that took up the time

Comment: Im starting to think it might be because of cache lines or such?

Comment: Yup I checked the assembly. With that single `*buffer='a'` in the destructor, a lot more assembly was added compared to without that.

Comment: With g++, remove all of the diagnostic prints from the destructor and the program compiles down to the malloc and the timing calls: https://godbolt.org/z/oehPdrbeY Visual studio seems stuck with everything, though: https://godbolt.org/z/E45zedxj3

Comment: You'd be surprised to learn how much code and complexity goes into `std::cout <<`.